# Why can't I find the Var keyword in my Visual C# 2008 Studio?

Tags: c#, variables, c#-3.0, keyword

I have this version:

> Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition

Using this function:

```
var X = new WebClient();
```

Var isn't recognized by my IDE. Thanks.

Comment: It helps if you display the actual compiler message.  The message that you would get if you were using var outside of a function pretty much tells the story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to use it for a class member?  `var` is only valid for local variables within a function.

Comment: Aha! That would be it my friend. Any logical reason as to WHY this is made this way? I'm new to using Vars. Is it because it would be system intensive because the compiler can't infer what type of variable is being saved to it?

Comment: @Papuccino1: See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx